# Use RxJava to monitor timeout for bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, rx-java

In my app, I'm using the [BluetoothSPP](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary) library to connect to a thermal printer. I have an activity, when started, that attempts to auto-connect to the device.

Now that I have this working, I want to implement a timeout feature. I thought using RxJava I could display a count down (of 5 seconds), then show the user a "retry" button if the time lapses. Here's what I have so far:

```
protected void onAutoConnectStarted() {
    count = 5;
    countdown.setText( count.toString() );
    countdown.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    retry.setVisibility( View.GONE );

    Observable.interval( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
        .take( 5 )
        .doOnNext( second -> {
            if (bluetoothSPP.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                throw new Exception("Break!");
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn( Schedulers.newThread() )
        .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() )
        .subscribe( second -> {
            count--;

            countdown.setText( count.toString() );
            countdown.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            retry.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }, error -> {
            countdown.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            retry.setVisibility( View.GONE );

            // This is good, we can move on and do stuff
            print();
        }, () -> {
            stopAutoConnect();

            countdown.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            retry.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        });
}
```

Basically, I want to update the timer display every second. In addition to that, I want the routine to exit if there's a successful connection or it hits 5 seconds - whichever comes first.

Although this code seems to work. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you try to do things not in the right places. With rxjava you always have some good alternatives, but in your case you should better update counter `onNext()`, show retry `onError()` and continue with successful bt connection `onCompleted()`. For example:

```
Observable
  .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .takeUntil(__ -> isBluetoothConnected())
  .takeUntil(Observable
      .timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .flatMap(timeout -> Observable.error(new TimeoutException())))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(
    secondsPassed -> updateCounter(),              //every second
    error         -> stopConnectingAndShowRetry(), //timeout
    ()            -> print()                       //bt connected
  )
```

Comment: Damnit! I didn't see `takeUntil`. I wouldn't have thought of the logic you suggest here in the early hours anyway

Comment: Just tried this, the timeout never occurs - according to the documentation, timeout is reset for every item that's emitted. In this case, the timeout operator is reset every second!

Comment: Yep, you are right. I made some changes. Now not so elegant)